# (C++) Finding the child type of a base type pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, types

I have a `class Base` and 4 classes `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, each derived from `Base`. I'm passing a pointer `Base*` to a function.

I know I can use the `dynamic_cast` to check for each separate child type. In order to find out which type that pointer is, I have to use 4 if statements which isn't practical.

Can this be done in some other, more elegant way?

- Or should I hold a `const int` variable in each subclass indicating its type to simple call `GetType()`?
- Or should I focus on making sure that when I have a storage - for example an inventory and `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` are different types of items - the items sort themselves (so that when I have 4 lists, the new item is placing itself on the proper list instead of having a function managing the inventory, checking for the type of the item and then placing it on the right list)?

Comment: Do you really even need to cast?  If you provide virtual functions you can do most things to the derived objects through a pointer to the base.

Comment: Problem is a common one. Comes up all the time. Usually people put an enum in the base class and make a member to identify the type. This sucks though in that the base class must have knowledge of every derived type. This occurs more with data objects then functional ones where a common interface is sufficient. Example: BaseResponse, CustomerResponse, CustomerFeedBackResponse...where each has more data members specific to the type. I don't know a better way though. We don't have reflection in C++. Maybe someone else has a better answer.

Comment: You could use `typeid` to index by derived type.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz There is a better way. That better way is too not try to bring down a generic code (code that uses interfaces and base classes) to a specific one (code that deals with concrete types). If you have done code that does dynamic casts to execute specific code for specific types, you should not need dynamic casts and have access directly to the specific type. If you cannot do that, you have architecture problem.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz by the way, if you gave a finite number of base classes, instead of a enum, you should use `std::variant`

Comment: @Guillaume You will always have to deal with concrete types when dealing with data.  class Contact{ std::string m_name } class Customer : public Contact { int m_id; std::string m_address }. It is very common to have some function or method somewhere that takes Contact and wants to know if it is a Customer in order to get its address if it is available. You cannot write it in terms of contact, because contact doesn't have the address.

Comment: You could look at double dispatch if each type should call a function with a different overload.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question? It seems perfectly legitimate to me. give the guy reasons if he needs to reformat his question somehow.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz "You will always have to deal with concrete types when dealing with data." it seems to be strange, but in OOD you do not deal with data, but with behavior ie interface. Data is encapsulated. So if you are dealing with data you are on procedural programming or mixing them both (which is even worse).

Comment: @ChristopherPisz "This occurs more with data objects then functional ones" this is clear sign that you came from procedural oriented programming. Do not take me wrong I am not saying it is wrong or worse, but OOD (and inheritance is part of that) is suppose to be done different way. All objects are functional ones due to the one of the main principle - data encapsulation.

Comment: I did not come from procedural programming. I came from the real world where I solve real problems, using the bits of OOD that C++ offers when _possible_ You can say anything you want from an academic perspective. In the real world, it doesn't hold true. I gave you examples. I'd write you an entire project on github to demonstrate if you like. Interfaces DO NOT have data members and should not have knowledge of concrete type data members. You cannot implement everything in terms of a common interface for all polymorphic types all of the time. It is a very common problem.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz "It is a very common problem." I totally agree - this is very common problem for procedural programmers who pretend they are using OOD, buy using that  "academic stuff when possible". That's why using `dynamic_cast` and it's simulation is a sign of improper OOD, you are not the first that solving it this way. You want it this way - it is fine for me. Just be frankly with yourself - you are not using OOD. And I am from the real world too and I do solve real problems. There are many ways: procedural, object oriented, functional etc. They all have their own pluses and minuses.

Comment: Slava, kindly piss off. I haven't programmed procedurally in my entire life. This isn't Facebook. Don't come here insulting people. If you'd like to show a better solution, then SHOW THE SOLUTION. Conduct your flame wars elsewhere.

Show me a method that maps As and Bs to Cs strictly through an interface, where B is derived from A, and A has data member foo, and B has data member bar. C has data members y that maps to foo, and z that maps to bar.

Comment: Slava, kindly piss off. I haven't programmed procedurally in my entire life. This isn't Facebook. Don't come here insulting people. If you'd like to show a better solution, then SHOW THE SOLUTION. Conduct your flame wars elsewhere. || Show me a method, taking an interface, that maps As and Bs to Cs strictly through said interface, where B is derived from A, and A has data member foo, and B has data member bar. C has data members y that maps to foo, and z that maps to bar. Do this without A or the interface having any knowledge of B. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

> Or should I hold a const int variable in each subclass indicating its type to simple call GetType()? Or should I focus on making sure that when I have a storage - for example an inventory and A, B, C, D are different types of items - the items sort themselves (so that when I have 4 lists, the new item is placing itself on the proper list instead of having a function managing the inventory, checking for the type of the item and then placing it on the right list)?

Neither one. You should properly design interface of the base class so when you use pointer to the base class you do not need to know what actual type it is, you just use interface. It is difficult to give you more details as there is no enough information in your question.

Note: using `dynamic_cast` directly or having function that simulates it (returning enum from virtual function that gives you particular type for example) is almost always a sign of improper design, though sometimes you may use that shortcut due to some technical reasons. But designing your app and thinking how you detect actual type from start - definitely wrong approach to OO design.

Note2: I assumed that you are doing object oriented design due to using inheritance and virtual functions. Though C++ is a multi-paradigm language and you can solve your issue different way. For example you can have `std::variant` with types `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` enumerated and use `visitor` to deal with each type individually or generically with a template function. But this is different approach than OOD and your classes may not need common base in this case at all. Of course you can mix them together but usually that does not lead to good design. When you mix different paradigms you get worst from each of them.

Comment: I assure you this in not at all possible in the real world when dealing with data rather than functionality. I'd write a thousand examples if there was space here for even one. I gave a very brief description in a comment on the OP's original question.

Comment: In a project I am staring at right now, I've got a BaseResponse that comes from a BaseResponse parser, a FooResponse that comes from a FooParser, and a BarResponse that comes from a BarParser. Each response has specific data members for its concrete type, but all share the data members if the BaseResponse. After Parsing, there is a method to map the different responses to some object in another system. You cannot write that in terms of an interface for the base. You have to map the specific data members of the concrete response type.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz I already mentioned in my answer that sometimes keep "ideal" OOD is not practical and you have to do shortcuts. But OP question shows wrong approach - he wants do deal with each concrete type in that function, which is very different.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz  "You cannot write that in terms of an interface for the base." You certainly can, how practical that would - different question. For example it is possible that decision so "After Parsing, there is a method to map the different responses to some object in another system." was not proper. It is difficult to give more details for abstract design.

Comment: Ok dude. I have 20 years and 100 projects written by 5000 people that say otherwise, but I'm not going to sit here and argue in a 500 character text box all day about it. Interfaces do not have or address DATA MEMBERS. Interfaces provide a contract with METHODS. To supply a method that has knowledge of concrete type data members is completely wrong.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz man I have similar experience, that does not change anything. There is base principle of OOD - data encapsulation. So there are no DATA MEMBERS visible to object clients, only methods. Yes I am not going to argue with you, you can design your application any way you want. But the fact that your design shows issues of improper approach (using dynamic_cast or enumerate types is definetly one of them) and there is reason for that, no matter what that 5000 people told you.

Comment: 5000 people didn't tell me shit and Ad-hominem is no way for you to win an argument. There IS NO OTHER WAY. PERIOD. Seriously, do you want a github example?

Comment: Show me a  "properly designed interface" that maps As and Bs to Cs strictly through an interface, where B is derived from A, and A has data member foo, and B has data member bar. C has data members y that maps to foo, and z that maps to bar. Do this without A or a common interface having any knowledge of B at all. I eagerly await your code.

Comment: Show me a method, taking a "properly designed interface", that maps As and Bs to Cs strictly through said interface, where B is derived from A, and A has data member foo, and B has data member bar. C has data members y that maps to foo, and z that maps to bar. Do this without A or the interface having any knowledge of B at all. I eagerly await your code.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz you already made decisions "C has data members y that maps to foo, and z that maps to bar" which is not OO design and asking me to fix it through proper interface. That does not work this way.

Comment: That is a business requirement. It has nothing to do with my design. It occurs all the time. Have you never worked on a project where mapping of data from one system to another was required?! I thought you said you worked in the real world and that "academic solutions always work in the real world, unless you are a procedural programmer." If A and B are in your domain, and C is in a third party domain. They've got an "OOD interface" to their component that only accepts objects of type C. You've got an "OOD project with a proper domain and inheritance hierarchy. What is your solution?